# Unable to test Express Model Sub-Generator

Tags: node.js, express, meanjs, karma-mocha, yo

I am generating an express model using yo model generator using the below command:

```
yo meanjs:express-model category
```

the model and its test gets created in a new folder "app" in my app.

When I try to run "npm test" now, the test should ideally run but I am not getting anything when I do npm test.

Below is the test file that gets generated:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var should = require('should'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    User = mongoose.model('User'),
    Category = mongoose.model('Category');

/**
 * Globals
 */
var user, category;

/**
 * Unit tests
 */
describe('Category Model Unit Tests:', function() {
    beforeEach(function(done) {
        user = new User({
            firstName: 'Full',
            lastName: 'Name',
            displayName: 'Full Name',
            email: 'test@test.com',
            username: 'username',
            password: 'password'
        });

        user.save(function() { 
            category = new Category({
                // Add model fields
                // ...
            });

            done();
        });
    });

    describe('Method Save', function() {
        it('should be able to save without problems', function(done) {
            return category.save(function(err) {
                should.not.exist(err);
                done();
            });
        });
    });

    afterEach(function(done) { 
        Category.remove().exec();
        User.remove().exec();

        done();
    });
});
```

Can anyone help me understand why am I unable to test this test using npm test?

Comment: What do you have in your package.json under "scripts.test"?

Comment: @Houseman I don't have scripts.test, I created the app using a yo generator. I only have scripts like this `"scripts": {
    "start": "grunt",
    "test": "grunt test",
    "postinstall": "bower install --config.interactive=false"
  },`

Comment: sorry, I have `"grunt test"` in scripts.test.